# Qt in Visual Studio 2013 with cmake - how do I get this to work?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, visual-studio-2013, cmake

I am currently trying integrate the library Qt in my C++ project. First I thought I could use it like any other library. I downloaded it, added the include path and libs to my VS project and tried a small sample of code that just creates a simple window with a text edit and a button. This worked and the small user interface was displayed.

Now I started to try implementing a class derived from a QWidget and realised, that it might not be that simple. The class I tried creating looked like this:

```
#include <QtWidgets\qstylepainter.h>
#include <QtWidgets\qwidget.h>

class MapRenderer : public QWidget{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MapRenderer(QWidget *parent = 0);
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event);
};
```

And the corresponding cpp file:

```
MapRenderer::MapRenderer(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent){
}

void MapRenderer::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event){
    QPainter p(this);
    p.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 3));
    p.drawPoint(QPointF(10, 20));
}
```

Now as I tried compiling this I started getting linker three linker errors that looked like this:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __cdecl MapRenderer::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@MapRenderer@@UEBAPEBUQMetaObject@@XZ)   G:\Documents\C++ Projects\HistoricalBorders\MapRenderer.obj
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __cdecl MapRenderer::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@MapRenderer@@UEAAPEAXPEBD@Z)
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __cdecl MapRenderer::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@MapRenderer@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
```

So I had a look around on the internet and found out that Qt apparently requires a far more complicated build process than a 'normal' c++ project with 'normal' libraries. I read of qmake and a Visual Studio Qt Add-In that can be used to create Qt-Projects in Visual Studio.

So I gave it a try and installed the Visual Studio Add-In and specified my Qt-version's root directory in its settings. Afterwards my project still wouldn't compile, but the only error message then was:

error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'

Now I don't really get this, because my Qt library is 64bit and my project configuration also is 64bit as well as all the other libraries I am using. Furthermore, before installing the add-in I didn't have this problem. I have to say, my project is a 'normal' Visual Studio C++ console application. I saw that since I installed the VS Add-in it is also possible to choose 'Qt-console application' when creating a new project in Visual Studio. I also gave this a try but it didn't even compile after creating it. I also don't really know what the difference of a "Qt-project" to a normal VS-project is, except that the Qt libraries are included by default.

The other thing I have to mention is that I am using cmake to create my VS project file because I use version control (mercurial) and multiple people shall work on the project.

At the moment I am totally confused on how to get this library to work.

Now what is my question? Honestly, I don't really know. What I'm asking myself is:

- Where does the architecture mismatch linker error come from?
- Can I create a normal VS console application and get it to work with Qt?
- What's the difference of a 'Qt-console application" to a normal VS project?
- Is it possible to generate a Qt-compatible VS project with cmake?

EDIT: Now I uninstalled the Add-In again, reinstalled it but am now getting the old linker errors again (no longer the architecture mismatch). I have no idea why.

EDIT: Ok, some clarification. Yes, I want to use cmake. I also already have a cmakelists.txt and a findQt.cmake that I wrote myself and that asks you for your Qt root directory and then adds the necessary include paths and library paths to the project. This also works so far. E.g. the following code compiles without problems and shows an interface:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
QTextEdit *textEdit = new QTextEdit;
QPushButton *quitButton = new QPushButton("&Quit");

QObject::connect(quitButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));

QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
layout->addWidget(textEdit);
layout->addWidget(quitButton);
QWidget window;
window.setLayout(layout);
window.show();
app.exec();
```

Now if I try to create a class as shown above (the `MapRenderer`) I get the linker errors also shown above. Now I thought I am doing something wrong. My only question is what. From your comment, drescherjm, I see that I problably missed the moc-step (sorry but I have no idea what exactly that is).

Comment: Hmm, it does not look like CMake is used at all in this. I think you were talking about qmake.

Comment: In the addon did you verify that it was using the 64 bit version of Qt and not some other Qt.

Comment: Sorry if that was not too clear. As I said I am currently generating my project files with cmake. I wanted a solution that works like this: you check out the sourcefiles from the repository and then run cmake that creates you a VS Project that afterwards compiles successfully with qt and that you can alter and will still compile. Maybe I should have a look into qmake, as it seems to be similar to cmake with the ability to support special steps necessary for Qt projects. And: Yes I am sure I was using the 64bit version, but see my edit, the error disappeard.

Comment: With CMake you do not need the addon although it helps debugging. I do not however understand some of your bulleted questions then. Are you trying to get rid of the CMake dependency? If not can you post a small CMakeLists.txt of your project so we can fix the moc problem. Running moc with CMake is pretty easy.

Comment: No, I would be happy if it worked with cmake. Please see my second EDIT. There I explain that again. I would be glad if you could tell me what that moc step is and how I can do it with cmake. I could also show you my current cmakelists file if that helps (don't want to post it here, it's pretty long).

Comment: I have used CMake for 6+ years on the day job with Qt / Visual Studio and I have never had this issue at all. There is something wrong in your CMakeLists.txt

Comment: ***adds the necessary include paths and library paths to the project.*** I hope you are using CMake commands for that and not manipulating the Visual Studio project files directly since CMake will wipe out all settings you make on the next configure.

Comment: ***Now if I try to create a class as shown above (the MapRenderer) I get the linker errors also shown above.*** Are you using the MOC commands in your CMakeLists.txt? It seems like moc is not being called or the generated moc_myClass.cpp files are not included in your targets.

Comment: No, I am not using any moc commands at the momoment. I didn't know I have to. Can you please tell me, how/where I have to add them and what they do?

And yes: I am adding the includes/libs in the cmakelists.txt via `include_directories(...)` and `target_link_libraries(...)`

Comment: Checkout this documentation: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/cmake-manual.html

Comment: Or this one for Qt4: http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/?title=Compiling_Qt4_apps_with_CMake

Comment: Thanks. I might have to add that I'm using qt5. I tried the automoc, but it apparently didn't do anything.

Might I have to tell cmake the path to my qmake executable? I tried  `set(QMAKE_PATH ${Qt_ROOT_DIR}/bin/qmake.exe)` but this didn't help. Note: I'm using a custom FindQt.cmake file.

Comment: You may want to try the more manual method like in the Qt4 example however with Qt5 commands instead of the Qt4 versions in your CMakeLists.txt. I can not help with Qt5 much nearly all of my development is still with Qt4.

Comment: I tried `set(QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE ${Qt_ROOT_DIR}/bin/moc.exe)` then `qt_wrap_cpp(HistoricalBorders MOC_SRCS MapRenderer.h)` and `add_executable(HistoricalBorders ${SOURCEFILES} ${MOC_SRCS})`. Now it adds a `moc_MapRenderer.cxx` to the project, but the file doesn't exist, it's just a dead link. Cmake runs without error messages.

Comment: I meant to use QT5_WRAP_CPP() although this old method looks deprecated for the newish automoc method. In cmake-gui advanced settings for Qt did it find moc? If I get time this weekend I will look into this.

Comment: The functions `qt4_wrap_cpp()` and `qt5_wrap_cpp()` don't exist anymore in the current version of cmake (3.1). That's also the reason my attempt using `qt4_wrap_cpp()` failed. Instead there is now the function I used. However, I generated the moc file manually using the moc.exe and now at least my project compiles, which is nice. I'm going to have a look what's the matter with cmake and maybe will make a new stackoverflow question out of this. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you have Qt project file (`.pro`) (or can get it somehow), you can run

```
cd <pro_folder>
qmake -tp vc
```

to (re-)generate Visual Studio project file with Qt build process properly set up, including

- `moc` (meta object compiler; that's what you are missing now),
- `uic` (processing designer's files)
- `rcc` (resource compiler).

All generated files will be compiled and linked properly.
You don't even need AddIn for that.